# Hadoop MapReduce not running 0%Map and Reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to run a Hadoop Map Reduce example on my machine and on running the job, I see the following message in my terminal. I have no idea what it means.

O/P

```
hadoop@anuvrattiku-Inspiron-13-7368:/usr/local/lib/hadoop-2.7.0/bin$ ./hadoop jar /home/anuvrattiku/Downloads/CardDriver.jar CardDriver input_dir output_dir
16/09/15 00:40:41 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/09/15 00:40:42 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/09/15 00:40:42 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/09/15 00:40:43 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1473915692030_0002
16/09/15 00:40:43 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1473915692030_0002
16/09/15 00:40:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://anuvrattiku-Inspiron-13-7368:8088/proxy/application_1473915692030_0002/
16/09/15 00:40:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1473915692030_0002
16/09/15 00:40:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1473915692030_0002 running in uber mode : false
16/09/15 00:40:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
hadoop@anuvrattiku-Inspiron-13-7368:~$ logout
You have new mail in /var/mail/root
root@anuvrattiku-Inspiron-13-7368:/usr/local/lib/hadoop-2.7.0/etc/hadoop#
```

Kindly help

Comment: Check the logs http://anuvrattiku-Inspiron-13-7368:8088/proxy/application_1473915692030_0002/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the way you submitted the mapreduce job. If you have submitted the job by using `job.submit()`, it will obviously submit the job and returns the control back. I think this is what is happening in your case.

If you have submitted the job using `job.waitForCompletion`, it will wait for the job to finish before returning the control, there by you can see the job processing on the console.

Check how you are submitting the job.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your map reduce does not gets correct queue for the job to submit .Check the queue where you submit the job .If you are using cluster then it must be getting the in the default queue this you can see in the yarn UI.
Set the queue name while submitting the job like

`-Dmapreduce.job.queuename=yourqueuename` after your jar .

or in the application like

```
hbaseConf.set("mapreduce.job.queuename", "yourquename");
```